# Route53 route subdomain to AWS Lambda getting 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, zappa, flask-jwt-extended

I have a domain in aws route53.

My frontend is routed to that domain from `cloudfront` via alias and works perfectly.

My backend sits on `aws lambda` and I want to put it behind my domain so my users can authorize using jwt cookies.

I created api.mydomain.com in `aws api gateway` with Base Path Mappings of /production -> pointing to my lambda
and tried to add my lambda using CNAME and Alias but neither worked, they return 404 when i call
https://api.mydomain.com/production/login

but when i call https://xxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/production/login it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create Record Set
2. Name: api.yourdomain.com
3. Type: Choose A – IPv4 address.
4. Type: Alias Choose Yes.
5. Alias Target:

Choose the list, and find the category API Gateway 
example: `https://xxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com/production/login`

Create, and then you are done. It will work